# How to get a Queryset from Django to use in a Template

Tags: python, django, orm

I have the following 2 Django models.  I have a Game model where multiple officials will be assigned to a game.  I have the Referee_Assignment model where I keep track of game assignments and whether the official accepted the assignment.  I want to query the two tables for all games and assignments and display in a table.  I have tried several different ways, but don't seem able to get all fields.  I am very new to Django.

```
class Game(models.Model):
    home = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='visit_team', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    gdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    gender = models.ForeignKey(Gender, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    level = models.ForeignKey(Game_Level, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    billing = models.IntegerField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    num_refs = models.ForeignKey(Num_Referee, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    enter_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    game_status = models.ForeignKey(Game_Status, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    season = models.IntegerField()


class Referee_Assignments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ref_assignments')
    position = models.ForeignKey(Referee_Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Ref_Assign_Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['game', 'position']
```

Here is the query:

```
    try:
        games = Game.objects.prefetch_related('ref_assignments')
        context = {'games': games}
        return render(request, 'assign/index.html', context)

    except:
        print('No Assignments')
```

Here is the Template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>Welcome to the Assignor Home Page</h1>

    <div class="container-games">
        <div class="settings__table">
            <table id="mydatable" class="display nowrap table table-striped" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date/Time</th>
                    <th>Day</th>
                    <th>Home</th>
                    <th>Visitor</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Level</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for game in games %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ game.gdate}}</td>
                        <td>{{ game.gdate|date:'l' }}</td>
                        <td>{{ game.home }}</td>
                        <td>{{ game.visitor }}</td>
                        <td>{{ game.location }}</td>
                        <td>{{ game.level }}</td>
                        <td>{{ game.gender }}</td>
                        <td>{{ game_ref_assignment.user_id }}</td>

                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'm not very used to use this function, but it looks like it's not really the right way to to (see doc here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)
Could you please detail the view where this query will be integrated?

Comment: What you have should work. What are all the fields you're trying to display? Which fields are you missing? A look at your template code may help.

Comment: I am not seeing the information or not sure how to find the information for the fields from Referee_Assignments

Comment: share your template